# Spring with JMX authentication

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I can register a Class into MBean but could not connect via jconsole. Why I could not connect running this application though I have disabled the jmx authentication via JVM parameters.

Here is my java Classes, spring property file and JVM parameters

```
package com.mkyong.jmx;

public interface JmxCoreComands {
    public void start();
    public void stop();
    public void report();   
}


package com.mkyong.jmx;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class JmxService implements JmxCoreComands {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Jmx Service start");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("jmx service stop");
    }

    @Override
    public void report() {
        System.out.println("jmx service report");
    }

}
```

**Spring property XML:**

```
<bean id="jmxAdapter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="SPRING:Name=TestRun">
                    <ref bean="jmxService" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <!-- managemethods property starts -->
        <property name="assembler">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.InterfaceBasedMBeanInfoAssembler">
                <property name="managedInterfaces">
                    <value>com.mkyong.jmx.JmxCoreComands</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- managemethods property ends -->
    </bean>
```

**JVM Parameters:**

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8014 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Xmx1024M 
-Xdebug 
-Xnoagent 
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8454,server=y,suspend=n 
-Djava.compiler=NONE
```

Comment: Are you unable to connect JVisualVM to the JMXServer at all, or do you just not find the MXBean? -- is there any error/exception?

Comment: BTW: You bean is a MBean not a MXBean (The naming convention for MXBeans is that the name of the interface ends with "MXBean") - But this should be no problem at the moment

Comment: I can telnet 8014 port, but I could not establish a connection via jconsole with blank username and password. I have used JMX severeal time so I am sure I am filling correct parameter into correct place. Besides there is not exception occur in java site

Comment: Is it a remote connection? Firewall? which connection string do you use?

Comment: Is your application a Webapplication that runs on a tomcat?

Comment: My application is J2SE application. When application started main thread is waits untill to get killed. At irst I am tring to connect locally.

Comment: have you tryed to connect directly to the process (JVisualVM list them below "Local") or have you tryed to add a connection via "Add JMX Connection"?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changed my JVM configuration as following I am able to connect the application over JMX.

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8014
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```